# Calculate High Low in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series

Here is my Data set with Index as Dates and Price Column. I want to create a column parameter(param) here which as follows in the comments column:

```
 Index          Price   |   param            Comments (P is Price)
1989-01-24      68.800      0               P <  P-1 (P-1 doesnt exist so 0)
                                            param = 0 , 

1989-01-25      68.620     -2               P < P-1 check P<P-2(P-2 doesnt 
                                            exist so P is a 2 day low and 
                                            param = -2 

1989-01-26      68.930      3               P > P-1, P>P-2, P-3(doesnt exist
                                            So P is a 3 day high, param =3 


1989-01-27      68.9900     4               P > P-1 > P-2 > P -3 and hence a 
                                            4 day high, param = 4                                            

1989-01-30      69.11       5               P > P-1> P-2 > P-3 > P-4 and 
                                            hence a 5 day high, param = 5

1989-01-31      69.070     -2               P < P-1 > P-2 and hence a 2 day 
                                            low, param = -2
```

Can someone please tell me an elegant way of achieving this in pandas?

Comment: what is the basis for forming the `param` column?

Comment: @piRSquared can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are searching for here, as per your comments section, my understanding is that `param` column is actually the rank of the value we are getting `Price` column. This is similar to finding the rank of a particular value in a stream of integers coming as an input. This could be achieved using PriorityQueue. You need to create a priority queue with a comparator that would store the elements in the priority queue in the increasing order of their values. For finding the rank, you would just need to iterate over the queue and find the index of the recent element in your column. This would, however, take O(n) time for finding the element index. Check below python documentation on how to create heapq or priority queue in python:

[HeapQ in python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html)

If you want to do this in O(logn), you can use self balancing BST like AVL or Red Black tree. The rank of the value for the recently entered element would then be its index from left side. This can be done in O(logn) time in worst case. Details for AVL in python:

[AVL tree using python](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Trees/AVLTreeImplementation.html)

Comment: I am still trying to understand what this means ! Would appreciate more help

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to group and rank with offset. Pandas has all of that included.

Here an effective linear solution to do that :

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'price':rand(15)})
df['ascending']=df.price<df.price.shift()
df['slope']=(-1)**df.ascending
df['group']=df.ascending.diff().abs().cumsum()
df['pseudorank']=df.slope.cumsum()
offset=df.groupby('group',sort=False).pseudorank.first()
df['param']=(df.pseudorank-df.join(offset,'group',lsuffix='old').pseudorank+2*df.slope)
df.param=df.param.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

For :

```
       price ascending  slope group  pseudorank  param
0   0.160806     False      1   NaN           1      0
1   0.068664      True     -1     1           0     -2
2   0.663227     False      1     2           1      2
3   0.273134      True     -1     3           0     -2
4   0.610329     False      1     4           1      2
5   0.595016      True     -1     5           0     -2
6   0.975163     False      1     6           1      2
7   0.692874      True     -1     7           0     -2
8   0.682642      True     -1     7          -1     -3
9   0.337418      True     -1     7          -2     -4
10  0.307546      True     -1     7          -3     -5
11  0.462594     False      1     8          -2      2
12  0.304216      True     -1     9          -3     -2
13  0.189434      True     -1     9          -4     -3
14  0.865468     False      1    10          -3      2
```

I create a lot of columns for explanation, you can delete them if you want.